# How to add google analytics code umbraco.i have already install google analytics packages in umbraco.Any one suggest

Tags: umbraco

How to add google analytics code umbraco.i have already install google analytics packages in umbraco.I have used window server i also added script code in template file.any one help

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough, just check your web site with 
 "Google Analytics Debugger" - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en